# Объединить таблицы при INSERT

Tags: php, mysql

Есть две таблицы:

`product` и `special`

в первой числовой id продукта и идентификатор в виде строки, типа: `7071bcada93d` , во второй связь продукта через числовой id. Но при внесении данных во вторую таблицу есть только строковой идентификатор.
Можно конечно сначала получить числовые id, через `SELECT id FROM product WHERE ident IN (a,b,c)`.
Но есть ли возможность объединить всё в один запрос?

Comment: При этом используется множественный инсерт, как я понимаю?

Comment: Слова плохо объясняют ситуацию. Показывайте - CREATE TABLE таблиц (текстом скриптов), пример наполнения (как INSERT INTO скрипты) и требуемый результат на именно таких данных. *есть ли возможность объединить всё в один запрос?* Да, можно.